# A carousel slideshow plugin in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, gallery, slideshow, jquery-ui

Am looking for carousel slideshow plugin that is similar to the one implemented [here](http://www.cadence.com/us/pages/default.aspx).

Any JavaScript slideshow that closely resembles that one would do. It does not even have to be a WordPress plugin, any standalone JavaScript library would also be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a plugin (discontinued): http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-imageflow/) and a Nextgen addon: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-imageflow/.

More samples and the original code (to the best of my knowledge) can be found here: http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/